# Dynamically create Eclipse Perspective with views

Tags: eclipse, swt, perspective

I can create an Eclipse perspective and add viewparts to it using plugin.xml and the declarative definitions.

However, I need to programatically create a perspective, set its name/title and add two viewparts to it in a split-view (one viewpart on the left and the other on the right).

I have searched the net and read through a lot of documentation but can't figure out how to do this. Does anyone have a small example of this? Maybe knows what to search for?

Answer (score 0):

You should be to create a new perspective via `IPerspectiveRegistry.clonePerspective(String id, String label, IPerspectiveDescriptor desc)`. Here the original perspective, `desc`, can be null, but I haven't found a way to set the image for the new perspective.

You can add the needed views via `IWorkbenchPage.showView(...)`, but have never figured out how to lay out the new view in the perspective...

Comment: Hi!

Thanks. I have a perspective definition in plugin.xml with the id of "com.acme.browser.perspectives.BrowserPerspective" which works as it should. Programatically, however, it does not work. What I have tried is this:

Comment: `code`IWorkbenchWindow window = getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IPerspectiveRegistry perspectiveRegistry = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry();
IPerspectiveDescriptor descriptor = perspectiveRegistry.findPerspectiveWithId("browser.perspectives.BrowserPerspective");
IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective = perspectiveRegistry.clonePerspective("browser.perspectives.BrowserPerspective.id2", "My new perspective title", descriptor);
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().showPerspective("browser.perspectives.BrowserPerspective.id2", window);

Comment: The error I get:

`code`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.PerspectiveRegistry.clonePerspective(PerspectiveRegistry.java:656)
 at browser.views.MyView$1.widgetSelected(SidebarView.java:58)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:228)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1176)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3493)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3112)

Comment: [I cannot match the line numbers...] From `cloneP(...)` I can see there are two things that can give an IAE: the label is empty - not the case here - or a perspective already exists with the specified id "....id2"... I guess the late is the case here.

Comment: The label is not empty and the ID is unique and only used in the clonePerspective and showPerspective methods. I assume that both of these ids whould be the same, right?

Comment: Yes, they should. I cannot test anything further right now, but for the record, which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse 3.4.2 build M20090211-1700

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to create the perspective from the ground up without cloning an existing perspective?

Comment: I can only see one way - though it is really a hack^10... You can use th `IConfigurationElement` version of the `PerspectiveDescriptor` with your own `IConfigurationElement` implementation. Note that you will need a fragment to invoke the constructor as it is internal. Needless to say: this cannot be expected to work across Eclipse versions... though I expect it to work with all 3.x editions :-)